# ¿Puedes ayudarme a entender esta función?

Tags: c++

Concretamente como funciona en algunos puntos, su función principal la entiendo, pero hay cosas que no. La función:

```
int get_number()
{
    const int not_a_symbol = numbers.size();    // not_a_symbol is a value that does not correspond
                                                // to a string in the numbers vector
    int val = not_a_symbol;
    if (cin >> val) return val; // try to read an integer composed of digits

    cin.clear();    // clear string after failed attempt to read an integer
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    for (int i = 0; i<numbers.size(); ++i)  // see if the string is in numbers
        if (numbers[i] == s) val = i;
    if (val == not_a_symbol) error("unexpected number string: ", s);
    return val;
}
```

¿Por que al principio tiene que realizar lo de asignarle a la variable constante **not_a_symbol** el valor del tamaño del vector? Dice que es un valor que no corresponde a una cadena en el vector de numeros, que por cierto, son numeros escritos en forma de cadena, "uno", "dos", ... , hasta "diez".

Entiendo que luego comprueba si lo introducido es true, o sea, es un entero, devuelve lo introducido, ¿no?

```
if (cin >> val) return val;
```

Limpia el cin.
Crea una cadena llamada s, y pide al usuario introducir un valor, luego comprueba recorriendo el vector de cadenas si el valor introducido corresponde con algun valor cadena almacenado. Si es asi, coge la posicion, que corresponde al valor entero del valor cadena almacenado y lo asigna a val, al final devuelve val, como valor entero.

Todo bien, la funcion se entiende, pero, en esa sencencia donde hace un error handle de esos, ¿como funciona? Vuelve a entrar en juego el **not_a_symbol**, que no entiendo. ¿Es como una referencia de lo que es un entero y lo que no lo es?

Edito y añado el código completo, por si fuera necesario. Es una sencilla calculadora que solo admite operaciones entre numeros de un digito, pero estos pueden ser tanto int como strings.

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h" 


    vector<string> numbers; // representation of numbers as strings
                            // numbers[i] is the string representation for i
                            // for numbers[0] to numbers[numbers.size()-1]

    void initialize_numbers()
    {
        numbers.push_back("zero");
        numbers.push_back("one");
        numbers.push_back("two");
        numbers.push_back("three");
        numbers.push_back("four");
        numbers.push_back("five");
        numbers.push_back("six");
        numbers.push_back("seven");
        numbers.push_back("eight");
        numbers.push_back("nine");
        numbers.push_back("ten");   // why not? :-)
    }

    int get_number()

    {
        const int not_a_symbol = numbers.size();    // not_a_symbol is a value that does not correspond
                                                    // to a string in the numbers vector
        int val = not_a_symbol;
        if (cin >> val) return val; // try to read an integer composed of digits

        cin.clear();    // clear string after failed attempt to read an integer
        string s;
        cin >> s;
        for (int i = 0; i<numbers.size(); ++i)  // see if the string is in numbers
            if (numbers[i] == s) val = i;
        if (val == not_a_symbol) error("unexpected number string: ", s);
        return val;
    }

    int main()
        try
    {
        initialize_numbers();

        cout << "please enter two floating-point values separated by an operator\n The operator can be + - * / % : ";

        while (true) {  // "forever"; that is until we give an unacceptable input or make a computations error
            int val1 = get_number();

            char op = 0;
            cin >> op; // get the operator

            int val2 = get_number();

            string oper;    // text appropriate for an operator
            double result;

            switch (op) {
            case '+':
                oper = "sum of ";
                result = val1 + val2;
                break;
            case '-':
                oper = "difference between ";
                result = val1 - val2;
                break;
            case '*':
                oper = "product of ";
                result = val1 * val2;
                break;
            case '/':
                oper = "ratio of ";
                if (val2 == 0) error("trying to divide by zero");
                result = val1 / val2;
                break;
            case '%':
                oper = "remainder of ";
                if (val2 == 0) error("trying to divide by zero (%)");
                result = val1 % val2;
                break;
            default:
                error("bad operator");
            }
            cout << oper << val1 << " and " << val2 << " is " << result << '\n';
            cout << "Try again: ";
        }
    }
    catch (runtime_error e) {   // this code is to produce error messages; it will be described in Chapter 5
        cout << e.what() << '\n';
        keep_window_open("~");  // For some Windows(tm) setups
    }
    catch (...) {   // this code is to produce error messages; it will be described in Chapter 5
        cout << "exiting\n";
        keep_window_open("~");  // For some Windows(tm) setups
    }
```

Comment: ¿Qué es `numbers`? ¿Dónde está declarado o definido? ¿Qué contiene? En tu código no aparece más que para ser usado

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Por que al principio tiene que realizar lo de asignarle a la variable
>   constante not_a_symbol el valor del tamaño del vector?

Es una medida de seguridad. Es un indicador que te permite saber si se pudo leer un número dentro de la función `get_number`. Si tu vector incluye números del 0 al 10, y regresas 11(`numbers.size()`), sabes con certeza que hubo un error al leer el número y puedes escribir lógica para manejar este caso de fallo en el código que llama a `get_number()`. Por eso la constante se llama `not_a_symbol`.

Lo anterior, claro, junto a lo demás que hace la función. Te explico:

- La función asigna el tamaño del vector de números a una constante(`not_a_symbol`), por las razones que escribí antes.
- Asignas esa constante que indica error a `val`, para en caso de que la lectura de `cin >> val` falle regresar ese mismo valor que indica error. Si `cin` no puede convertir lo que le diste y asignarlo a una variable, en este caso `val`, estará en un estado que al ponerlo en un `if` te permite usarlo como un valor booleano.
  Todo esto para manejar el caso de que el usuario introduzca los números como son: "5", "10", etc. y no uno de los strings de `numbers`.
- `cin.clear()` reestablece las banderas de cin.
- Ahora cambia la táctica, intentamos leer un string que representa el número, ya que la lectura de un `int` falló. Este nuevo número puede contener lo que sea.(`cin >> s`).
- Ahora en el `for`, recorremos el vector elemento por elemento a ver si lo que escribimos, contenido ahora en `s`, corresponde a alguna de las posiciones del vector. Por ejemplo, si escribimos "one", y la segunda posición del vector(`numbers[1]`) contiene "one", a la variable entera `int` llamada `val` se le asigna la posición que coincidió, en este ejemplo: 1. Así convertiríamos algo como "one", o "uno" tal vez, en un `int`, aprovechándonos de la manera en que está organizado el vector(`numbers[10]` siempre contendrá el string "10" o alguna manera de representar 10, "diez", "X", etc.).
- Ahora viene la función principal de `not_a_symbol`. Si en el `for` anterior no encontramos lo que escribimos, entonces no escribimos un número válido, y nunca se reasignó `val`, así que sigue valiendo lo mismo que `not_a_symbol`(11 en este ejemplo). Hacemos esa prueba en un `if` y si son iguales, indica que el número no fue válido y llama alguna función de error.
- Al contrario, si `val` no vale lo mismo que `not_a_symbol`, eso quiere decir que coincidió con alguna de las posiciones de `numbers` y ahora `val` contiene algún valor que va del 0 al 10, y regresamos ese valor.

Y reitero, 11 es utilizado porque es el primer valor que es una posición inválida para el vector del ejemplo, no hay doceavo elemento [11].

Answer (score 0):

El objeto `std::cin` es un flujo de entrada de datos ([`istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream)); pueden darse errores cuando se realiza una lectura de datos con formato (usando el [operador de extracción `>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)). Si sucede un error durante la lectura el objeto de lectura (`std::cin`) quedará en estado erróneo, con alguna de sus [banderas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdstate) de error activa; los objetos de flujo de datos tienen un [operador de conversión a booleano](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool), que devuelve `false` si alguna de las banderas de error está activada, por lo tanto la línea:

```
if (cin >> val) return val;
```

Significa: "*Si al leer en `val` desde `cin` no ha habido ningún error, devuelve `val`*". En caso contrario, la función sigue adelante pasando al control de errores, por lo que veo: restablece las banderas del flujo de datos con la función [`clear`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) e intenta leer de nuevo el flujo de datos, en esta ocasión en una variable de texto, que es menos restrictiva que un entero (`int`); lo hace así para mostrar por pantalla un texto de error comprensible; asumo que si introduces el número `Patata` se mostrará un mensaje de error parecido a: `unexpected number string: Patata`.

> ¿Por que al principio tiene que realizar lo de asignarle a la variable constante `not_a_symbol` el valor del tamaño del vector?

Aparentemente es una acción inútil, ya que lo primero que se hace con `val` es reescribir su valor con la lectura desde el flujo de entrada de datos, pero ese valor podría no cambiar, dependiendo del estándar de C++ en que hayas compilado:

- **Antes de C++11**: `val` no es modificado, por lo tanto contiene el valor `not_a_symbol`.
- **Después de C++11**: Se escribe `0` en `val` si la lectura falla por datos incompatibles (leer texto en números). Si la lectura falla por salirse del rango de datos se escribirá (dependiendo de la situación) el máximo o mínimo valor aceptable por el tipo de datos.

Interpreto que el código que muestras asume que se usará un compilador previo a C++11, de manera que devolverá un valor fuera del vector `numbers` que podría ser usado como [código de error](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_de_error)... pero comprobamos que no es así ya que el código que has proporcionado usa el retorno de la función `get_number` sin verificarlo, por lo que el propósito de asignar `not_a_symbol` a `var` sigue siendo un misterio.

Comment: ¿Y el  not_a_symbol es necesario?¿No se conseguiria lo mismo declarando simplemente val como un entero?

Comment: Estoy buscando información del operador `>>` para acabar de completar la respuesta, su comportamiento cambió en estándares recientes.